# SSRS report using 2 datasets- trying to combine them both in 1 table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am creating a SSRS report. I am using 2 datasets. I use 1 dataset to show a dropdown list of paramets and the 2nd dataset to show a relevant table. This is working great.However, I am trying for my report to show first column from Dataset1 (that i use as a parameter for dropdown) and the remaining columns from dataset 2 that are related. I have added column and inserted the expression for lookupset but that does not seem to help (it returns a blank column). I would appreciate any feedback to include 2 datasets in 1 report.

What I have right now: 
Dataset1 - pulls a list of unique providers - shows that as a dropdown list.
Dataset 2- pulls 2 random clients related to that unique provider in dropdown list and gets displayed in a table form.

I am trying to create a report where the user will have the ability to pick "all" from the provider parameter dropdown and then the report will show entire list of distinct providers and 2 random clients that are related to the provider.

### cloumn 1(dataset1)   Column 2 (Dataset2)

1. Provider1

   ```
        random client 1
        random client 2
   ```
2. Provider2

   ```
        random client 1
        random client 2
   ```

provider3........

Comment: You may want to change your second data source's generation code, so that if "All" is selected it runs a different extraction routine than if a single provider is selected. Frequently, the best thing to do with your code is not to make it more versatile, but to make it more specialized, and this could be the case here.

Comment: Can you show the code you have in each dataset, plus a screenshot of your report design or what you expect it to look like and note on the image what's not working.